# Sequential unique IDs for PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

[PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) best-practice recommendation is to use `PUT` instead of `POST` for creating a new document (analogous to a row in an rdbms) primarily because the latter generates a random ID that makes it inefficient for subsequent sorting of the data. `PUT`, on the other hand, requires providing a user-generated, unique ID.

I am a bit puzzled that PouchDB doesn't seem to provide this functionality out-of-the-box. So, what is the best way to generate a unique, sequential ID (analogous to PostgreSQL's sequence)? I could use something analogous to `maxID`, but the main issue, in my view, is to ensure no one else inserts a record between when I determine the maxID and when I actually succeed in inserting a record.

Suggestions?

Comment: Good question! Right now I'm using GUIDs generated like described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript). Depending on the implementation of the random number generator this might be a good practice...

Comment: well, I am not sure what the point is of using GUIDs since you can always get those by using `POST` as I mentioned above. The key is to have something unique yet predictable and sortable to accommodate PouchDB. The best would be something that imitates Postgres's sequence

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have the complete answer, a suggestion would be to try something like Twitter's [Snowflake ID](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids.html).
If there is a JavaScript implementation, this might be an option.

A simpler version would be to simply use

`var id = (new Date()).getTime();`

which returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Edit: the [following article](https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/generate-unique-identifier-nodejs-javascript/) suggests a couple of Node packages:

- [uuid](https://npmjs.com/package/uuid)
- [flake-idgen](https://npmjs.org/package/flake-idgen)

Comment: all the examples I see in the documentation mention using the time, yet obviously it's possible at some point for two clients to generate a timestamp during the same millisecond.   UUIDs seem to be a lot of overhead when e.g. you're using it to generate an id for eacj element in a document, while snowflake ids seem limited at arbitrary partition boundaries: e.g. what if you have more than 32 clients, or 32 processes on a client?  Overall this seems to be not just a hard problem, but an *impossible* one to solve efficiently in a distributed environment.